# Make Interceptors for multiple form-login with different namespace in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, interceptor

I have two http patterns, It is corresponding with two login forms . One for User login with namespace default "/", one for Admin login with namespace "/admin".
I have a problem when I make interceptors for each login form.

The errors happened when I inputted wrong url at admin's login form. (eg .../admin/sdfsdfa). I doesn't redirect to admin's login form

```
"Unable to load page,because Too many redirects".
```

My spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http pattern="/login**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/admin/" security="none" />
<http pattern="/admin/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/admin/adminLogin"
        login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check"
        default-target-url="/admin/adminAccess" authentication-failure-url="/admin/adminLogin?error"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-url="/admin/j_spring_security_logout"
        logout-success-url="/adminLogin?logout" />
</http>
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/user/403.jsp" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/userAccess"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>
<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

When I login with user's login form (namespace default "/"). It works well, It can intercept all requests so We can't access any url without login success. It automatically redirect url into url user's login form.

But when I login with admin's login form (namespace default "/admin"). 
I see spring-security interceptors work wrong or doesn't work. At namespace of admin "/admin". When I input wrong url (eg .../admin/sdfnsdfe). It doesn't redirect into admin's login form
It display error "Unable to load page,because Too many redirects".
I think url have matched all above patterns, So the errors happened.
Now what things I need do to resolve this problem ?
Do you think I should make namespace for user login is "/user" replace namespace default "/" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you input URL like `/admin/sdfsdfa`, the URL match a pattern of `/admin/**` which you define it as a secured resource with `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />`.

As the user is not authenticated, he is redirected to the login page `/admin/adminLogin`. After the redirect, the request URL match the pattern of `/admin/**` and redirect to `/admin/adminLogin` again. As a result, you get `Too many redirects`.

Please try to set your login page of `/admin/adminLogin` with `security="none"` and add:

```
<http pattern="/admin/adminLogin" security="none" />
```

before

```
<http pattern="/admin/**">
```

This can disable the Security filter chain for the request path of `/admin/adminLogin`